# circunferências responsivas em lugares específicos

Tags: html, css

Olá,

Eu estava a colocar circunferências e cima de pontos específicos de uma imagem mas eu gostava que elas reduzissem o seu tamanho mas sem sair da posição que eu quero, eu tentei usar % tambem tentei usar vw mas nunca fica parado do lugar especifico da imagem e dependendo da medida do monitor as circunferências ficam demasiado pequenas.

Eu queria saber qual era a melhor forma de colocar algumas circunferências responsivas num lugar especifico da imagem sem que elas andem de um lado para o outro com a resolução do brower.

Neste Exemplo eu queria que a circunferencia fica-se em cima do cigarro como fica em FullScreen mas que mante-se a mesma posição quando se reduzi-se o screen

O meu objetivo é fazer parecer que o circulo faz parte da imagem mas depois quando clicas no circulo aparece um pop-up

Codigo:

```css
.imagensdesktop {
        display: flex;
    }

    .imagensdesktop .img-fluid {
        padding: 5px;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
    }

    #circulo-modal {
        border: solid white 2px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
        top: 0;
        width: 4.5vw;
        height: 4.5vw;
    }

    .c-1 {
            margin-top: 18.5%;
margin-left: 12.5%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container imagensdesktop">
    <div id="img-1">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616328774543-60eef730c6f3?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=622&q=80" alt="img-1" />
      <div id="circulo-modal" class="c-1" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalCenter1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: já tentou usar medidas em `%` no lugar de `vw`? *viewport* pode tbm ser influenciado por barras de rolagem

Comment: @RicardoPontual ja tentei usar %, VW, ate com algumas pesquisas encontrei uma coisa chamada EW mas tambem nao funcionou

Comment: Coloca #img-1 {position: relative;width: max-content} e arruma novamente as porcentagens para colocar o círculo no lugar certo

Comment: @hugocsl e em relação a circunferência para quando a imagem ir reduzindo o circulo ir reduzindo também para parecer que o circulo mantem o mesmo tamanho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solução:**

Primeiro, coloque #img-1 com `position:relative` ou as porcentagens vão se aplicar com relação ao primeiro elemento que não tenha `position:static`. Neste snippet é o `html`, por isso só em "fullscreen" que o círculo se encaixa.

Sua imagem mede originalmente 622x967 pixels.

**Posicionamento:**

O posicionamento do div é dado pelo seu canto superior esquerdo.

Fazendo um quadrado na imagem original começando em 237,351 até 314,428 (para conter o circulo).
Temos o canto superior esquerdo deste quadrado estará a 100x237/622 = aproximadamente 38% da margem esquerda e 100x351/967 = aproximadamente 36% da margem superior.

**Tamanho:**

Este quadrado desenhado tem dimensões 77x77 pixels. Fazendo as proporções temos que o div do círculo é de 12% da largura da imagem e 8% da altura.

Seu CSS ficaria assim:

```css
.imagensdesktop {
display: flex;
}

.imagensdesktop .img-fluid {
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#img-1 {position:relative}

#circulo-modal {
    border: solid white 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.c-1 {
    top: 36%;
    left: 38%;
    width: 12%;
    height: 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container imagensdesktop">
    <div id="img-1">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616328774543-60eef730c6f3?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=622&q=80" alt="img-1" />
      <div id="circulo-modal" class="c-1" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalCenter1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigada pela ajuda e pela explicação!